# C++ - global pointer to function

Tags: c++, c, pointers

why this works? I think global data are "initialized" at compile time (compiler saves to .global section in obj file format null bytes, so when the section is loaded into memory, it is initialized to null). So how can be initialized pointer to function address, if compiler doesn't know where the function will be in memory at runtime?

```
#include <iostream>

void vypis();

int neco;
int * bla = &neco;
void (*vypis_ptr)() = vypis;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

}

void vypis() {

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the compiler is bothering with any of that? There is nothing in main, so it has nothing to do, so it wouldn't need to include any of the problematic code.

Comment: @PhilH, sure it has to, vypis_ptr is a externaly visible object.

Comment: This kind of address resolution is not necessarily done by the compiler, but by the loader. The only important thing that it is done before the program starts. Also, at least theoretically these things are different for C and for C++. In C++ this could even be a constructor that would be run after the program starts but before it enters in `main`.

Comment: @JensGustedt post it as answer, that's an important piece of info

Comment: @JensGustedt thx, post it as answer, so i can accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed the redundant include of `iostream` so that your source actually compiles as C and compiled it on my system to an executable called vypis. Here is what I found:

```
$ nm vypis | fgrep vypis
00000000004004d0 T vypis
0000000000600888 D vypis_ptr
```

So, `vypis`, a function, is a global in the "text" section and `vypis_ptr`, a pointer to a function, is a global in the "data" section.

Objects in the data section have values stored in the executable and I can read what's in `vypis_ptr` by dumping out the data section with `objdump`.

```
$ objdump -d -j .data vypis

vypis:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .data:

0000000000600878 <__data_start>:
        ...

0000000000600880 <__dso_handle>:
        ...

0000000000600888 <vypis_ptr>:
  600888:       d0 04 40 00 00 00 00 00                             ..@.....

0000000000600890 <bla>:
  600890:       a8 08 60 00 00 00 00 00                             ..`.....
```

Here we can see that the value `4004d0` is stored in `vypis_ptr` but this is exactly the location of `vypis` as displayed in the output of `nm`.

Comment: hm but why there are names of my variables in obj file?

Comment: @Krab Because they’re global and you made them visible (by not having declared them as `static`) so they can be exported and used in other compilation modules. And the names need to be there so that the linker can find the symbols.

Comment: @Krab: `-d` means disassmeble and this option uses information from the symbol table to annotate the addresses in the output of the data section.